# Remove duplicate lines from lots of files recursively

Tags: command-line, bash, cygwin

I have a directory tree of a few thousand folders consisting of an ungodly amount of total lines - about 2 or 3 times my system's memory.

I could have run `uniq` or `sort -u` inside of a `for` loop but I want to be able to guarantee that whatever I do won't be destructive to this huge, very sensitive dataset, and am willing to wait a little longer for the process to complete if it means being able to guarantee these things.

For these reasons I need a solution that:

1. Removes duplicate lines inside of each file, *not* across the whole set
2. Does so in-place, leaving lines inside their original files and the file and folder structure unchanged

What's the safest way to do this?

Comment: Are the duplicate lines next to each other ?

Comment: @JustKhaithang Yes, each file is sorted.

Comment: If files are already sorted you can try sed. `delete duplicate, consecutive lines from a file (emulates "uniq"). First line in a set of duplicate lines is kept, rest are deleted.
 sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D'`. Source http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt